# Checking Login.php - Blank Page?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm working on a basic login system. I've used a lot of sources and many places of the code are extracts from other login systems online. The problem is that I am simply and gracefully getting a completely blank page when inputting the username and password into `loginpage.html` and when it redirects it to this file, BLANK PAGE.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include 'connectingshit.php'; 

//Basically naming a session and starting one
session_name('litLogin');

//The cookie is going to live for 2 weeks
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);

//Now we actually start the session
session_start();
ob_start();
if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['RemainLoggedIn']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the cookie (browser restarts)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    // Destroy the session
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    //I hope I know what I am doing, this is supposed to hold our errors.
    $errors = array();

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $errors[] = 'All the fields must be filled in buddyboy!';
    if(!count($errors)) 
    {
      //Assigning the input form shit to the variables/strings or wtf they are
      $tinkerbells_username = $_POST['username'];
      $tinkerbells_password = $_POST['password'];
      $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

      // We remove all dangerous characters (!!!!) WTF? Escaping them "WOW"...
      $tinkerbells_username = stripslashes($tinkerbells_username);
      $tinkerbells_password = stripslashes($tinkerbells_password);
      $tinkerbells_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $tinkerbells_username);
      $tinkerbells_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $tinkerbells_password);

      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc('SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = "$niloquieroser_username" AND password = "$niloquieroser_password"');

      //Does basically the username exist when $row lookes for it in the database
      if(($row['username']) && ($niloquieroser_username == $tinkerbells_username && $niloquieroser_password == $tinkerbells_password))
      {
    //Now fortunately or unfortunatley if it did work and everything is fine
    //We can continue.....
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

    //We store some data in the session
    setcookie('RemainLoggedIn',$_POST['rememberMe']);
    //cookie gets created
  }
  else $errors[]=("Wrongs username or/and password!");
    }
    header("Location: success.html");
    exit;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: So what's the error? please mention the error so we could know where to look

Comment: Can you indent your code, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc('SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = "$niloquieroser_username" AND password = "$niloquieroser_password"');
```

MySQL strings should be single-quoted; you're calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on a string, not a query object; your variables won't be interpolated, since the PHP string uses single quotes. Not that you should interpolate them anyway; use prepared statements.

Also, please hash your darn passwords.

Comment: @omullumo: An emphasis on making it work, not safe, is the reason 50% of security flaws exist. Don't do that. Anyway, check your error log. I bet you have `display_errors` turned off.

Comment: I think I remember mysql allowing double quotes on string values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix your query. You can't embed php values in strings without define your strings with double quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT id, username, password FROM members WHERE username = '$niloquieroser_username' AND password = '$niloquieroser_password'";
```

You want to use [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to get a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) set. Then you can loop through that like so:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //echo $row['username'];
    ...
}
```

If you manage to get your script working properly, note that it seems like even if the username/password was invalid, you still redirect them to `success.html`. You should put `header("Location: success.html");` inside the `if` that checks the result set for a row only, and echo the error message if the row was not found.